# No idea how to read in a DF into another DF to make changes

Tags: r

I am attempting to solve the problem

> 1.(10pts) Read the data into a data frameand handle incorrect/inconsistent data typesNote: There are no UTF-8 or special characters in the data.
>   Output variables:oraw_df: read the data without colClasses,
>   na.strings, orstringsAsFactorsto see how R interprets each column
>   movie_df: using the arguments of read.csv()and/or the as()function,
>   transform the columns with incorrect data types

For the second part, I have no idea how to reference the data frame "raw_df" to use it to link into the new movie_df

```
movie_df<-raw_df(as.factor(raw_df$IMBD))
```

This is what I have tried as it makes the most logical sense, however it says that R can't find function raw_df, and obviously this isn't a function so I have no clue how to even attempt to start this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Read and include features from [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269), especially the part about reproducing and pasting your data. The dataset is not available for us to demonstrate with; think of using a smaller example that can be included in your question.

Comment: Presumably your data is somewhere? It is hard from the question to know where ( a .csv or .xlsx that was provided to you?) .